# git show using notepad

Tags: git, github

I would like to view a previous commit using Windows notepad. I'm trying out the code below in powershell but with no success. Please advice.

```
git show notepad HEAD^4:index.html
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
git show HEAD^4:index.html > results.txt && start notepad "results.txt"
```

And open the resulting text file in notepad. You can change the path of the file to where you want.

Edit: I added a part to open the text file. You may need to specify the full path to the file if it can't find it.

Comment: when I entered the command you proposed, I got this message: "The token '&&' is not a valid statement separator in this version". My version is 1.8.0.msysgit.0

Comment: You could run the two commands separately, which would also work. That's interesting the && doesn't work. If you replace the `&&` with `;`, that's the Linux style of concatenating commands. See if that works.